# How to get expiration_intent from Apple's subscriptions Server notifications?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

According to the documentation in the below link, Apple subscriptions status server will send this field expiration_intent when users renew their subscription.

> Apple's
>
> This is the same as the Subscription Expiration Intent in the receipt.
> Posted only if notification_type is RENEWAL or INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html

I'm getting all the notifications on my production server and have checked all the logs for RENEWAL or INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL types but never been able to get the value for this field.

Any idea why this is happening? though I'm getting the rest of the fields with their values.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug, or a mistake in the documentation (one of many). I have only encountered this field when validating a receipt, where it will appear in the `pending_renewal_info` info (and only if `auto_renew_status` is 0).

Here is an OpenRadar I recommend duplicating: http://www.openradar.me/33937017